# Map Snowflake Response with Dictionary Value Types

Tags: c#, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

How do I use a dictionary of Types (i.e Value = String) as a data model.

I.e. Im querying Snowflake using Snowflake.Data. I've got the desired types in a dictionary from a previous method and want to map them up.

I don't want to use Expando due to performance reasons.

At the moment, I have this:
var sfresponse = await snowflakeClient.QueryAsync<ExpandoObject>("SELECT * FROM " + SFTable);

But I want to replace the "QueryAync<ExpandoObject>" with a dictionary that has the columns and the types.

I have a dictionary of the column values and the types. I want to map the types with a json response from Snowflake.Data